# CiviEvent iCal download for some users is in Central time when we expect it to be in Eastern time

Tags: civievent

We're running CiviCRM 5.63.3 on Drupal. Our organization is in Florida which has both Eastern and Central time zones.

I have a longstanding problem - some of our members will register for an event I have created for noon eastern time and when they download the .ics file the event displays in their calendar for noon Central time. The event is set up in Eastern time. Most of our members, including all the members who send me emails about this, are in Eastern time.

Here is the [iCal file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N90BO0Gwk5-McebH5x6cyyHkWsGMrKMb/view?usp=sharing) and the [google calendar link](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?text=Mid-Session+Briefing+2024&dates=20240126T120000/20240126T130000&details=+%0D%0A%0D%0AThe+60-day+Florida+Legislative+Sessions+began+January+9th.+Join+us+for+an+update+on+the+good+and+bad+bills+that+are+making+their+way+through+committees.+%0D%0A%0D%0AThis+presentation+will+be+recorded+and+available+later+in+case+you%26%2339;re+not+available+on+Friday+at+noon+EST.+%0D%0A%0D%0APlease+click+the+grey+%26%2339;Register+Now%26%2339;+button+below+to+register.+%0A%0A%3Ca+href%3D%22https://forms.fnps.org/civicrm/event/info?reset%3D1%26id%3D119%22%3EView+Lunch+and+Learn+Details%3C/a%3E&location=FL+%0D%09United+States%09&trp=false&sprop=website:https://forms.fnps.org/&ctz=America/New_York).

Here's the live [Event Info page](https://forms.fnps.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=119) for your reference.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: There is no attachment and the google link triggers a direct import that means I can't look at the code. However, I would suspect that looking at the ical invite would simply reveal that the timezone is set to Central. You'll need to check your CiviCRM or CMS settings for timezone information.

Comment: @Valerie welcome!  Could you please edit your question to mention your CMS (Drupal, Wordpress, Backdrop, Joomla) and your CiviCRM version?  The version can be found at the bottom of all CiviCRM pages in the footer.

Comment: Thanks @JonG-MegaphoneTech, done.

Comment: @kapn, my apologies, have properly linked them this time. Our CRM isn't in Central and the google calendar result is in Eastern time and the event time also displays properly in eastern time in both the Event Info and Online Registration pages

Comment: @Valerie Thanks for posting the file and link. Both are working for me and showing Eastern Time. I think something has changed because your previous google calendar link definitely exhibited the behaviour you describe. I downloaded your ics and examined it and it looked fine, so I tested it and all was well. A test of the link also worked now. Is it still failing for you?

Answer (score 5):

Our Drupal installation was, unbeknownst to me, set to Central (Chicago) time.

[image: screenshot of our Drupal Regional Settings page]

This didn't affect me as a registered user because I had previously set my timezone to Eastern (New York) so the .ics files I uploaded above were in the correct (Eastern/New York) timezone. @justin-freeman-agileware and @kapn are not registered users in our system so they were given .ics files in Central time.

This also explains why this problem was restricted to a limited number of our members, as many of our members were likely interacting with CiviEvent as registered users via tokens we sent them via email.

So, to summarize, people interacting with our Civi install as unregistered users were downloading iCal invites with our default timezone, which was incorrectly set to Central/Chicago time.

Comment: And just for the record, it is your website / content management system (CMS) that sets the timezone. Not "Civi".

CiviCRM reads the timezone information from the website. CiviCRM is not the Website, it's a different system which is connected to the website.

Comment: Oh, right, that screenshot above is from Drupal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@valerie can you amend your question to include the correct timezone for your Event and also what timezone is set in your CMS? CiviCRM will use the CMS timezone when generating these files and if that's incorrect then the output will be incorrect also.

It looks like you have since changed the CMS timezone because the current ICS results differ from your original question.

Original ICS file in GDrive.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviEvent iCal//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:20240126T170000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:CiviCRM_EventID_119_0712e127d1846c6226284cfbaab67375@forms.fnps.org
SUMMARY:Mid-Session Briefing 2024
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"><html><body><p><img al
 t="" src="https://forms.fnps.org//sites/default/fi
 les/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/yt%20thumb%2
 0comp(1).jpg" style="width: 400px\; height: 225px\
 ;" /></p>\n \n <p>The 60-day Florida Legislative S
 essions began January 9th. Join us for an update o
 n the good and bad bills that are making their way
  through committees.</p>\n \n <p>This presentation
  will be recorded and available later in case you&
 #39\;re not available on Friday at noon EST.</p>\n
  \n <p>Please click the grey &#39\;Register Now&#3
 9\; button below to register.</p></body></html>
DESCRIPTION:\n \n \n \n The 60-day Florida Legislative Session
 s began January 9th. Join us for an update on the 
 good and bad bills that are making their way throu
 gh committees.\n \n \n \n This presentation will b
 e recorded and available later in case you're not 
 available on Friday at noon EST.\n \n \n \n Please
  click the grey 'Register Now' button below to reg
 ister.\n \n 
CATEGORIES:Lunch and Learn
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
DTSTAMP;TZID=America/New_York:20240126T120000
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20240126T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20240126T130000
URL:https://forms.fnps.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=119
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Updated ICS file from CiviCRM, https://forms.fnps.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=119

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//CiviCRM//NONSGML CiviEvent iCal//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Chicago
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
TZNAME:CST
DTSTART:20240126T180000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:CiviCRM_EventID_119_0712e127d1846c6226284cfbaab67375@forms.fnps.org
SUMMARY:Mid-Session Briefing 2024
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"><html><body><p><img al
 t="" src="https://forms.fnps.org//sites/default/fi
 les/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/yt%20thumb%2
 0comp(1).jpg" style="width: 400px\; height: 225px\
 ;" /></p>\n \n <p>The 60-day Florida Legislative S
 essions began January 9th. Join us for an update o
 n the good and bad bills that are making their way
  through committees.</p>\n \n <p>This presentation
  will be recorded and available later in case you&
 #39\;re not available on Friday at noon EST.</p>\n
  \n <p>Please click the grey &#39\;Register Now&#3
 9\; button below to register.</p></body></html>
DESCRIPTION:\n \n \n \n The 60-day Florida Legislative Session
 s began January 9th. Join us for an update on the 
 good and bad bills that are making their way throu
 gh committees.\n \n \n \n This presentation will b
 e recorded and available later in case you're not 
 available on Friday at noon EST.\n \n \n \n Please
  click the grey 'Register Now' button below to reg
 ister.\n \n 
CATEGORIES:Lunch and Learn
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
DTSTAMP;TZID=America/Chicago:20240126T120000
DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20240126T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20240126T130000
URL:https://forms.fnps.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=119
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! We haven't changed our timezone in Civi since I downloaded the iCal file and uploaded it to the google drive. I hadn't checked our timezone in Civi before but I just did and it's in Central time! *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks Valerie.